# DateTime in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

```
$shippedtime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/y',$csv[$j][3],$timezone);
//  $shippedtimeformat = strtotime($shippedtime->format('Y-m-d'));
//$shippedtime2 = $shippedtimeformat->modify('-1 day');
//$shippedtime3 = $shippedtimeformat->modify('-2 day');
//$shippedtime4 = $shippedtimeformat->modify('-3 day');
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $csv[$j][8]);
//original query
$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM orders where ShippingName = '" . $name . "' AND ShippedTime LIKE '" . $shippedtime->format('Y-m-d') ."%'");
```

I am trying to get the past 3 days in the correct format so I can run them in the MYSQL query below. However, none of them are returning in the correct format for MYSQL to use. How would I get the correct date format so I can run the query so if the name matches AND (shipped time like %) or (shipped time -1 like %) or (current time -2 like %) or (current time -3 like %)?

Comment: Bind parameters, concatenating SQL query is first step to **SQL Injection**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @lad2025 that you should bind the parameters. Since you didn't ask for that, I'll answer it with a concatenated query. If orders.ShippedTime is a DateTime field, you can't use LIKE. That's for string fields. Instead, use BETWEEN.

```
$name = str_replace("'", "''", $name) // sanitize $name
$query = $mysqli->prepare(
    "SELECT *
     FROM orders
     WHERE ShippingName = '" . $name . "' AND
        ShippedTime BETWEEN '" . $shippedtime->format('Y-m-d') ."' AND
        '" . $shippedtime->format('Y-m-d') . " 23:59:59.999'");
```

Note: If you don't specify a time, MySQL assumes midnight of that day.

Comment: $shippedtime is a date that is read in from a CSV file. How do I modify the $shippedtime to be 3 days in the future?

Comment: thanks...and this is a daemon server side script so i didn't bind the parameters as there should not be any malicious formatted input since the input is controlled